# Java Array Size Initialization

Tags: java, arrays

I'm reading a book "Java: A Beginners Guide (5th Edition)" by Herbert Schildt and I keep noticing a peculiar method of declaring arrays.

Here's my own example to personify this practice:

```
public int[] generateArray(int size) {
    int[] x = new int[size+1];
    return x;
}
int[] y = generateArray(3);
```

Now, what this author is doing is ALWAYS creating the array with `+1` to the size. I do not understand why he would do this. Is it avoiding `ArrayOutOfBounds` exceptions? Furthermore, why not just send in 4 instead of 3 if he's already going to increment it by 1?

Here's an example from his book to clear up the ambiguity of this question:

```
// A dynamic queue.
class DynQueue implements ICharQ {
    private char q[];
    private int putLoc, getLoc;
    public DynQueue(int size) {
        q = new char[size+1]; //allocate memory
        putLoc = getLoc = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to ask the author. It's **exactly** the same as passing 4 (and not using +1) in your example.

Comment: Why not ignore his idea if you disagree?  It's one object reference - four bytes.  Not a terrible waste.  I agree - I wouldn't write it this way.

Comment: It's not a matter of reading the authors mind -- there could very well be a known reason behind this. Or... it could very well be a personal convention in which this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: I think it can start loops from 1 to N+1, to show well ordered numbers. still it doesnt sense to me

Comment: @duffymo I never said I agreed or disagreed, I'm simply trying to understand.

Comment: I think you do understand it.  Hence the question.  My personal opinion?  The Schlidt books are rubbish.  I'd use the online tutorials.  They're good and up to date.

Comment: maybe this would make more sense in context, posting some of Schildt's code using this kind of thing. it's like he wants the parameter to hold the last index instead of the actual size.

Comment: @NathanHughes the code examples are a bit long winded. What do you mean by hold the last index?

Comment: an array declared as int[n] is indexed from 0 .. n-1, creating an array with n elements using your method would require passing in n-1, which is the last index.

Comment: first you would have to understand the example properly from that book to get an idea why is there a +1 for the index. this is a broad question and may attract multiple answers and most would be guesses. can someone please close it or mark it off topic

Comment: At least when it comes to C and C++, Herb Schildt is absolutely notorious. "...having heard horror stories about Herbert Schildt's *C: The Complete Reference*, I decided to check it out. I flipped the book open; I found glaring errors. I paged through it. I found more glaring errors." http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html

Comment: That explains him using quotes in a switch statement using `int`s

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, I added a snippet example from his book. It's a queue example

Comment: May be the author has started learning programming with a 1-based index language like ALGOL, COBOL or Fortran.

Comment: Or coldfusion! (I use coldfusion at work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know this book, but this example is totally misleading! Basically `new int[3+1]` will initialize an int array of size 4, not 3. Given a method `int[] generateArray(int size)` I would absolutely expect that it will generate an array of size passed as the argument, not a one that is size + 1. The only way the method could make any sense is naming it: *generateArrayThatHasLastIndex(int lastIndex)*. Any other way it is wrong.

Comment: I added an example from the book. No more misleading!

Answer (score 5):

The habit may be akin to certain types of arrays in languages such as C which use null bytes to serve as terminating "sentinels" to indicate the end of an array; an example would be ["C-strings"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm), which take the form `char[]` or `char *`.

That being said, Java is not C, and why the author chooses to do this eludes me. It's misleading and would absolutely be considered bad practice.

Your remark on doing this to mitigate `ArrayOutOfBounds` exceptions could be correct too, but creating an array of a different size than intended is not the proper way to go about it.

EDIT:

Based on the example you've given, I would say that the application for this habit of creating "misleadingly-sized" arrays is nothing more than a function of the problem that the code is designed to solve.

For instance, it's possible that the `DynQueue` is being constructed this way because the first or last index represents data that is to be differentiated from the rest of the data in the array somehow... perhaps `q[0]` (the first element of the queue) represents *the* `char` that is the 'next' to be considered in some algorithm or processing (it's at the "front of the line" so to speak), but has not been cleared out of the array yet.

(That still doesn't change the fact that the way it is done is questionable.)